# Multithreading In Jersey REST API

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, tomcat, jersey-2.0

Let me explain with an example, suppose there is a REST API say /getUsers
and now this API needs to collect data from 3 to 5 other systems say system1, system2 and system3 and send the combined result back as a response of /getUsers API.

Now in order to reduce the processing time I would like to make calls to system1/2/3 parallel using multi threading.

What are some of the good approaches to process such request using multithreading in the REST API? like should I maintain my own thread pool and executors or should use one provided by jersey or servlet container? what would be the impact and how to handle when the number of concurrent requests increase?

I am okay with clients waiting for the response and don't want to take approach of queuing the requests and sending HTTP 202 and later processing them. I am also aware of jersey async apis but I more looking towards optimizing the processing time within the API

I do realize it is a bit of a broader question, just looking out for some tried and tested design and techniques to process such requests.

I am using Jersey REST implementation, Tomcat Server and application is Java based.

Regards

Comment: Check out implementation with spring-client - can be done the same with jersey async https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: This should be two completely different questions:  (1) How do I implement a REST service? and (2) How can I use threads to simultaneously request data from two or more services?  The answer to either question should have no bearing on the other, and the structure of the code that you eventually write should show that.  Unfortunately, neither of those two questions are really appropriate for this forum.  This is more of a place where you show us some code that behaves differently from the way you expected it to behave, and we help you to understand why.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am aware of async method it helps in releasing the worker threads back to the servlet container pool but what I am looking for is how to multithread my business logic task within the rest api so that the request is processed in least amount of time.

Comment: Thanks @jameslarge my question is number 2, how can I use threads to simultaneously request data from two or more services within my rest api.

Comment: Like I said, That's kind of a broad question for this forum.  I'd use a _thread pool_ (e.g., `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`), and I'd write a method that submits one _task_ to the thread pool for each of the requests that you want to make.  Each task would submit one query to a remote service, await the reply, and then return some object representing the result.  Meanwhile, the top-level method gets back a `Future` for each task that it submitted.  It would use the Futures to wait for and obtain the results, and finally, it would combine the results and return to its caller.